# Openstack Error: Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries (Kypo Cyber Range)

Tags: installation, instance, openstack

I am trying to install `kypo` cyber range by following its official [guide](https://docs.crp.kypo.muni.cz/installation-guide/base-infrastructure/) in all-in-one mode of `openstack` deployment. While  creating Base Infrastructure `./create-base.sh`, I am getting below error exceeding maximum retries. It successfully built security `security groups` and `networking` stack. However head and proxy are generating Errors.

```
2022-03-30 07:53:00Z [kypo-head-stack]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Stack CREATE started
2022-03-30 07:53:01Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head-port]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:53:05Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head-port]: CREATE_COMPLETE  state changed
2022-03-30 07:53:08Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:53:08Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head-floating-ip]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:53:25Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head-floating-ip]: CREATE_COMPLETE  state changed
2022-03-30 07:54:41Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: CREATE_FAILED  ResourceInError: resources.kypo-head: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance 20fdda13-f5fa-4378-bf60-c64f0bf52371., Code: 500"
2022-03-30 07:54:41Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:54:46Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: DELETE_COMPLETE  state changed
2022-03-30 07:54:50Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:55:28Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: CREATE_FAILED  ResourceInError: resources.kypo-head: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance 130604ae-a7d6-42f4-9010-56524561b4a0., Code: 500"
2022-03-30 07:55:28Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:55:35Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: DELETE_COMPLETE  state changed
2022-03-30 07:55:40Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 07:56:21Z [kypo-head-stack.kypo-head]: CREATE_FAILED  ResourceInError: resources.kypo-head: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance ad4be42c-fecb-43bc-881b-b8d6f0e17527., Code: 500"

Stack kypo-head-stack CREATE_FAILED 

2022-03-30 07:59:53Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Stack CREATE started
2022-03-30 07:59:54Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump-port]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 08:00:03Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump-port]: CREATE_COMPLETE  state changed
2022-03-30 08:00:03Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump-floating-ip]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 08:00:05Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump]: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  state changed
2022-03-30 08:00:15Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump-floating-ip]: CREATE_COMPLETE  state changed
2022-03-30 08:00:48Z [kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump]: CREATE_FAILED  ResourceInError: resources.kypo-proxy-jump: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance 8d300d3f-1fdd-430e-b271-57eb5b1cbb8a., Code: 500"
...

Stack kypo-proxy-jump-stack CREATE_FAILED
```

Comment: Do you enough available resources to launch the stack? The error messages all refer to "instance ...", check the nova-compute.log as well as nova-scheduler.log and nova-conductor.log, also placement log could reveal any resource bottlenecks.

Comment: @eblock nova-compute.log says `: libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Emulator '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' does not support virt type 'kvm'` I am using vmware with 4 VCPUs and 10G Ram

Comment: Then you probably should change the `virt_type` in your nova.conf to match your actual setup.

Comment: I did change it, but after running with new configuration, it is still generating previous error like changes are not being enabled. I am changing in nova-compute/nova.conf.

Comment: How exactly did you setup your all-in-one deployment? I'm not familiar with these tools like devstack etc. But maybe someone else can chime in then. Just to make sure, after changing nova.conf you restarted the service, correct?

Comment: I have used kolla ansible to setup deployment. Now I am building instances for kypo head and proxy. I have tried service openstack-nova-compute  restart but it saying unit nova-compute.service not found. However logs are working.

Comment: So which nova process is running then?

Comment: I eventually restart the vm in order to get rid of all hustle. Now there is another error showing `Message: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available., Code: 500"`. When I look at nova-compute log it says `Failed to connect to libvirt: unable to connect to server at '192.168.211.133:16509': Connection refused'`. Internet says checks for baremetal nodes but I am running vmware ..

Comment: You should ensure that nested virtualization is enabled, I believe otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Nested Virtualization is enabled in vmware and kvm is also working fine now. I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further log exploration of nova-compute.log said that `libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Emulator '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' does not support virt type 'kvm'`. I changed the virt_type to qemu but error some how persisted. The root cause in my problem was I was running VM on VMWare without enabling `Virtulize Intel VT-x/EPT` which enables nested virtualization.

I check this box under VM Settings > Processor and the error went away.